# Why can't I use variables (using "%s" or "?") to refer to table and column names in sqlite's "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" and "INSERT INTO VALUES"?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, oop

I am creating a database class for my application since I'll need database tables at various occasions. I am using sqlite3 and I need my code to be as generic as possible but when I used "%s" and/or "?" for the table name and the column titles I got the above mentioned error.

Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("cows.db")
c = conn.cursor()


class databases:
    global c

    def __init__(self, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name

    def create_table(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s)', (self.table_name, args))
        c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)", (self.table_name, kwargs))
        conn.commit()

    def delete_record(self, *args):
        c.execute(''' DELETE FROM ? WHERE ? = ?''', (self.table_name, args))
        conn.commit()


cows = databases('cow')
cows.create_table('cow_id REAL', 'lactation_phase TEXT', 'milk_production REAL', 'weight REAL')
```

Here's the error message:

```
C:\Users\farid\PycharmProjects\cownutritionmanagmentsystem\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/farid/PycharmProjects/cownutritionmanagmentsystem/database.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/farid/PycharmProjects/cownutritionmanagmentsystem/database.py", line 24, in <module>
    cows.create_table('cow_id REAL', 'lactation_phase TEXT', 'milk_production REAL', 'weight REAL')
  File "C:/Users/farid/PycharmProjects/cownutritionmanagmentsystem/database.py", line 14, in create_table
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s)', (self.table_name, args))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Comment: Positional parameters (`?`) in prepared statements _cannot_ be table or column names.  They can only be used to represent _values_.

Comment: if you need to use %s,  try ```c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s)' % (self.table_name, args))```

Comment: so does that mean that I can't create multiple tables with different table and variable names whenever I create a new instance of the databases class? If its not possible, Are there any suggestions how that could be done?

Comment: Table and column names have to be known when a statement is compiled to bytecode, thus they have to be hardcoded in the query, not parameters bound at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%s` to refer to the table name or other variables in the string.
Notice the `%s` marker to insert a string, and the `%d` marker to insert an integer.

Alternatively, you can also use the `format` method to substitute the value of a variable in the string.
In `format` method, the curly braces show where the inserted value should go.
You can insert multiple values using this method and values do not need to be only string but it can be numbers and other Python objects.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("cows.db")
c = conn.cursor()


class databases:
    global c

    def __init__(self, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name

    def create_table(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s)' % (self.table_name, args))
        c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)" % (self.table_name, kwargs)) # Notice how we have used % operator here
        conn.commit()

    def delete_record(self, *args):
        c.execute(''' DELETE FROM {} WHERE {} = {}'''.format(self.table_name, args)) # We have used format method here
        conn.commit()


cows = databases('cow')
cows.create_table('cow_id REAL', 'lactation_phase TEXT', 'milk_production REAL', 'weight REAL')
```